# android button customized color and round corner

Tags: android, button, colors

I am making a drawing app where the users can choose a custom color. After choosing the color, the customBtn would change its color to the chosen color by the following code:

```
     customBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(alphaSeekBar.getProgress(), redSeekBar.getProgress(), 
        greenSeekBar.getProgress(), blueSeekBar.getProgress()));
```

However, this makes the button to be squared-corner.

I would like it to be round-corner and when pressed, it become grey in color.

There is `selector.xml` already exist and shown as follows, but how could I incorporate all the things together such that

1. it will show custom color when not pressed, round-cornered, and
2. when pressed it become grey (and maintain round-cornered)?

### Selector:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >         
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/black" />
        <solid android:color="@color/grey"/>
        <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="2dp" 
            android:right="5dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
        <corners android:radius="5dp" /> 
    </shape>    
</item>

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/black" />
        <solid android:color="@color/???-- how to amend---??"/>
        <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="2dp" 
            android:right="5dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
        <corners android:radius="5dp" /> 
    </shape>
</item>
```

### EDIT: to set round-corner programmatically, as customerized color is not static, user can change the customerized color upon request

```
 customColorCode = Color.argb(alphaSeekBar.getProgress(), redSeekBar.getProgress(), 
         greenSeekBar.getProgress(), blueSeekBar.getProgress());         



 RoundRectShape rs = new RoundRectShape(new float[] { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}, null, null);
 ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(rs);
 customBtn.setBackgroundDrawable(sd);
 customBtn.setBackgroundColor(customColorCode);
```

### Programmatically problem:

The button before choosing customerized color is showing round corner perfectly, set after choosing the customerized color it is then back to squared-color, possibly it is because the setBackgroundColor line is put at the last code. Yet i have tried move it up and yet still being squared color. How can this be modified?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't supporting the full range states like a normal button (focused, disabled, pressed, active, etc, etc), and the only difference between your default state and your pressed state is a solid color. Maybe a `[PorterColorFilter][1]` would work. I think you can set the pressed state as is, and have the default state simply be white. Then you apply the color filter to the button with the set custom color. You might need to try a few filter modes, but I think `DST_ATOP` will replace the white, but not the black border. And you will probably want to use a gesture detector to remove the color filter when a down `MotionEvent` is triggered on the button (also known as your pressed state being triggered).

The short answer is that Android Buttons don't work well for what you want to do. They tend to require static drawables that define their appearance in the different states they can be in.

One option is to restrict the color choices and create a drawable for each color, and set the drawable based on the user's choice. I don't know what context your button occurs in, but it's recommended to follow the touch feedback example for a normal button to provide consistency for the user.

Note: `setBackgroundColor` is misleading, it's just setting the Button drawable to a color drawable, which is replacing your rounded rectangle drawable. That's why it's becoming a rectangle when you do that.

Comment: I have seen some examples that set programmatcally. I have editted the code using the above. The button can be showing corners before setting the customerized color. Yet after choosing the customerized color, it become squared-corner again. Do you know how to further modify programmatically? thanks!!

Comment: I example why it becomes square in the last paragraph. `setBackgroundColor` == `setBackgroundDrawable`, where the drawable is a `ColorDrawable`. In other words, it replaces the drawable you set in `setBackgroundDrawable`. Further, `View`s are rectangular areas of the screen, and the `ColorDrawable` will just fill that area with it's color.

Comment: You have to make the rounded rectangle the color you want, not set a rounded rectangle shape and then apply a background color. This means either the color is set when you create the rectangle, or you use a color filter on top of it.